# C++ MySQL - Failing getting column names

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm trying to get the column names of my table. I'm using this code:

```
MYSQL_RES *res_set;
    MYSQL_ROW row;

    string query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM `data`";

    mysql_query(this->_connect, query.c_str());
    res_set = mysql_store_result(this->_connect);

    if(mysql_num_rows(res_set) == 0){
        printf("> error. mysql did not return any rows for the given player name.\n");
    }

    row = mysql_fetch_row(res_set);

    cout << row[4];
```

The first column in the row is corrent. But the following ones(here '4') are anything else like `char(255)`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I'm not wrong SHOW in nothing in MySQL. Try SELECT if you've read about it.

Comment: @AsimAwan:  The `SHOW` command returns details about the columns.  The `SELECT` command returns the data from the columns.  See also `DESCRIBE` command, as in `DESCRIBE data;`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use single quote around the table name:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM data;
```

I highly recommend you open up the MySql Monitor window.  When in doubt, type the commands into there to verify.

I use a debugger and breakpoint before sending the command.  I copy the text from the command and paste into the MySQL monitor window to verify.

**Edit 1: The DESCRIBE command**
You can also use the DESCRIBE command:

```
DESCRIBE data;
```

**Edit 2: Retrieving value from column**
If I misunderstood you, retrieving data from a column uses the SELECT command:

```
SELECT column1  
FROM  data;
```